# Why this jquery else if statements are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Could you please take a look at this? It does not work. I can not figure out why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result = parseInt($('#kmi').text());
  if (result < 18, 5) {
    $("#line1").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 18, 5 && result < 24, 9) {
    $("#line2").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 25 && result = < 29, 9) {
    $("#line3").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 30 && result = < 34.9) {
    $("#line4").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 35 && result = < 39.9) {
    $("#line5").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 40) {
    $("#line6").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else {
    $("#line1").css("background-color", "#fff");
  }
}
});
```

Comment: what is `result<18,5`?

Comment: Change '=<' to '<=' in all the conditions

Comment: First job when debugging JS is to check the console for errors. You have several syntax problems. Secondly, the `if` statement is pure JS. It has nothing at all to do with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `=>` instead of `<=` where the former one will be considered as an assignment operator and there was an extra `}` closing braces.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result = parseInt($('#kmi').text());
  if (result < 18, 5) {
    $("#line1").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 18.5 && result < 24.9) {
    $("#line2").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 25 && result <= 29.9) {
    $("#line3").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 30 && result <= 34.9) {
    $("#line4").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 35 && result <= 39.9) {
    $("#line5").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else if (result >= 40) {
    $("#line6").css("background-color", "#eee");
  } else {
    $("#line1").css("background-color", "#fff");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do you expect from this `if (result < 18, 5)` ?

Comment: I was going to ask him the same question. I think he meant `18.5`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should change comma to dot and you have used  => instead of <= and don't use much else if statement you can use one class property for all lines because all CSS having same property background-color, "#eee" something like this , please check the condition for if statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var result = parseInt($('#kmi').text()); 
if(result<18.5 || result>=40){
$(".lines").css("background-color", "#eee");
}else{
    $("#line1").css("background-color", "#fff");
}

}
});
```